# When is it worth it to get Will of the Ancients on other champions to help out the AP carry?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have tried WotA on Amumu in the jungle, since it seems to work relatively well with his kit, and can help out some AP carries a fair amount, so I've found it's worth getting. But for other champions, I'm not sure. For instance, when playing Janna or Soraka, who benefit somewhat from AP, what makes getting WotA to help your AP carry out from the aura? Is there a way to measure the effectiveness of WotA for them, and under what conditions make it good to sacrifice the items you would normally build in order to buy WotA?

Comment: Hello! Questions such as this typically cause a lot of discussion and opinions in the answers section. In general, questions based in fact are a much better fit for this site. Questions with situational answers, on the other hand, are hard to pin down to a "best answer". :)

Comment: @Shaun well said, this quote should be in review comments.

Answer (score 1):

First off: Best use of WoTA is in a double AP lineup, where top and midlane play AP and both get WoTA and profit from each other.

Whether or not to get WoTA on Support champs like Soraka, Janna or even Blitzcrank depends on a few factors:

1. How much does your AP benefit from WoTA? There are some high cooldown AP champs that don't even benefit that much from WoTA. Right off the bat I can only think of Lux, but there are plenty more that don't really need Spellvamp that much. Other champs, which deal more consistent damage over time profit more from WoTA (eg. Ryze, Cassiopeia)
2. How fed are you as support? WoTA is a rather expensive item, considering that it doesn't give a lot of defensive stats to yourself. ANd as support in lategame it would often probably be better to be able to take a little more damage and help your teammates with your abilities a little longer. WoTA seems to me like a luxury item on supports, that you only get when you're already really strong and ahead in gold.

Comment: agreed the only time I get it is when I get some early kills with lulu... and my mid is building wota and we don't have an ap top

Answer (score -1):

It is more worth it to get a WotA when more of your team comp benefits from AP such as hybrids like akali or jax. As it will be helping more than just your AP carry. Also if your AP is behind or fairly fed it will give them either a boost to catch up or get ahead. Also spell vamp is helpful to everyone because landing that last second long ranged skill shot may be just what u need to stay alive.

Answer (score -1):

Getting WotA is good on a support in very few situations.  Normally in a double AP game, both APs will already be getting WotA, rendering a 3rd one useless (core for morde, vlad, kennen, rumble, etc).  You should also be getting Aegis before WotA as support, unless someone else is getting it.  If you don't have double AP, then you should be getting a Zeke's after Aegis.

However.. if you're running double AP where neither one has it and your jungler got 
Aegis, that's a great time to get WotA and help the team.  Or if you've already gotten Zeke's, have Aegis, have Shurelia's, you're not getting focused too much, and have the gold... then go for WotA.